# How make a collection of type which is generic type in c#

Tags: c#, generics, nested-generics

I have class like the following

```
public class Relation<T1, T2> where T1: Entity where T2: Entity
{
}
```

I want to make class derived from a list/collection which is of the type Relation

```
public class RelationList<T>: List<Relation>> 
{

}
```

I have tried in SO but couldn't get things right. Even right pointer to SO will also help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because your `Relation` class is generic you have to specify generic types when you derive from `Relation`.

Either as

```
public class RelationList: List<Relation<MyEntity2, MyEntity2>>
{
}
```

or as

```
public class RelationList<T1, T2> : List<Relation<T1, T2>> 
        where T1: Entity
        where T2: Entity
{
}
```

If you want `RelationList` to be able to keep `Relation<T1, T2>` no matter how `T1` and `T2` is specified you should use additional interface:

```
public interface IRelation
{
}

public class Relation<T1, T2> : IRelation
    where T1: Entity where T2: Entity
{
}

public class RelationList : List<IRelation>
{
}
```

Comment: Marcin is right. Additionnally i would like to add that it is not smart to inherit from List, for various reason. IMHO in many cases it's cleaner to encapsulate the instance of underlying list and to add your specific methods, and possibly IEnumerable / class indexer (for example) if you would like to iterate on your type.